# Как проверить функционирование master-slave в MySQL?

Tags: mysql

Настроил Yii2 по инструкции на запись в master и чтение из slave, но мне кажется, что все запросы идут на master. Как проверить?

Comment: SHOW PROCESSLIST - годный вариант?

Comment: Да, вполне, однако, если запросов будет мало и они будут отрабатывать слишком быстро - вы можете ничего не увидеть.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Включите логгирование запросов в MySQL (оно по умолчанию отключено из соображений производительности). Для этого в конфигурационном файле my.cnf, в секции [myqld] следует создать следующие директивы

```
general_log=1
general_log_file=/path/to/log
```

Вместо /path/to/log следует подставить путь к лог-файлу. Логгирование включается после перезагрузки сервера. Чтобы следить за логом в реальном времени, можно воспользоваться командой tail, передав ей параметр -f и при необходимости количество выводимых последних строк

```
tail -200f /path/to/log
```